# Where does the DSC file name prefix come from?

Tags: nikon, file-management, filenames

Without having a real problem with this, why did Nikon (maybe others too?) chose this file name prefix?

Comment: Additionally, I noticed that Nikon uses "CSC" for photos converted from RAW in-camera after the fact (using the menu-based interface for doing so).

Comment: @mattdm - in my experience every image you make some in-camera adjustment to, not just from raw, is saved as a copy with "CSC" prefix.

Comment: HTC smartphones also store images in a DSC directory, but name them imgxxxx

Comment: Yes, but what does "Digital Still Camera" mean?

Comment: A "Still" is a photograph, not a movie.

Comment: HP cameras use the "HPIM" prefix.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**CIPA (the Camera & Imaging Products Association) has long established DSC as meaning *Digital Still Camera.*** This prefix is not mandated by the DCF (Digital Camera Filesystem) standard but was adopted uniformly by Nikon and Fuji which named their files starting with DSC_, DSCN, or DSCF. Other manufactures went with PICT, PIC or P which presumable all stand for *Picture*. Although plenty of cameras also save videos with the same convention.

You will notice that DCF requires files in AdobeRBG color-space to start with an underscore, in which case DSC is often all that is left and you get _DSCxxxx.yyy uniformly for Nikon and Fuji.

*As ahockley pointed-out, Sony coincidentally uses the DSC prefix for fixed-lens camera names as well.*

Comment: What is CIPA?  A quick googling reveals several uses for that acronym, none of which seem to apply to imaging...

Comment: @ahockley Camera & Imaging Products Association

Comment: The Sony DSLRs also use the DSC prefix.

Comment: I wonder why canon don't use this too... I think they default to IMGxxxxxx.

Comment: The Canon EOS 50D names files as `_MG_xxxx.CR2` (where `xxxx` are digits) when shooting in RAW with AdobeRGB selected. (The camera offers a choice between AdobeRGB and sRGB.)

Answer (score 7):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyber-shot), the Sony Cyber-shot cameras use the same prefix:

> All Cyber-shot models have a DSC prefix in their names, which is an acronym for "Digital Still Camera".

I suspect Nikon adopted the same convention.