# What's the difference between DSC_ and RSC_ files?

Tags: nikon, lightroom

My Nikon cameras (D80 and D700) both seemingly randomly change file extension between DSC_ and RSC_. Counter does not reset. I always shoot RAW and rarely change memory card (as I import photos directly from camera to Lightroom) or any file quality related settings in the camera.

This is relatively minor issue, but ruins filename based sorting. Does anyone have any idea why that prefix changes, and is there a way to avoid that?

I know that as a workaround, Lightroom supports file renaming during import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a widely established convention to use the DSC prefix, [indicating "digital still camera"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/15726/4390). I'd suppose RSC would indicate "reflex still camera"; or, in case it only gets used for retouched files (such as when using lens correction profiles) "retouched still camera" (D90 uses "CSC" prefix in such cases). Some Nikons are also known to [alternate file name based on color space used](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/photography/9781435454347/setup-playback-and-shooting-menus/ch03lev1sec3) by relocating underscore in the name (_DSC for AdobeRGB and DSC_ for sRGB).

On higher end Nikons, there's an option in Shooting Menu to define your own preferred 3-character file name prefix, I'd expect that to resolve the issue on D700 (but not D80, which doesn't have the setting). Note that if you use custom settings banks, the setting must be specified individually for each bank.

Comment: Not sure about the D80 or D700, but some high-end Canons have customised shooting modes (numbers on the PASM-dial), which each have their own settings. If one were to adjust the file prefix and save it to those, then any photo taken with 1,2,3 modes might seemingly "randomly" have a different prefix to the photos taken on PASM or Auto.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the prefix used in your files, under the configuration menu, I assume you have two profiles with different settings, and are switching between them.

Answer (score -1):

Picture(s) edited within the camera are changed from DSC to CSC.

Comment: This answer needs much more explanation. Question is about DSC and RSC, not CSC. What about the already accepted answer do you find insufficient?