# Why is Nikon camera prefixing filenames with an underscore (for example _DSCxxxx)?

Tags: nikon, filenames

It suddenly changed. The old version was DSC_XXXX. I want it this way; how can I change it back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the DSC file name prefix come from?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15726/where-does-the-dsc-file-name-prefix-come-from)

Answer (score 19):

You changed from sRGB to Adobe RGB1998?

It's apparently the naming convention. It surprised me too when I did the same thing.

From my D5500 manual...

> Photographs are saved using file names consisting of “DSC_” or, in the
>   case of images that use the Adobe RGB color space (0 243), “_DSC”,
>   followed by a four-digit number and a three- letter extension (e.g.,
>   “DSC_0001.JPG”). The File naming option is used to select three
>   letters to replace the “DSC” portion of the file name.

The only way to revert is to go back to sRGB, or rename later in your computer.